# Magento 2 handle WEBAPI error and success Response for multiple data input

Tags: webapi, response, api-response

I have an input data like this for my custom web api:

```
"data":[{"sku":"BM0011","warehouse":"kklm","qty":"5"},{"sku":"YU9982","warehouse":"cvxs","qty":"2"}]
```

I need to validate the data and run the update inventory function and catch an error if there's any. Since this has multiple data that I need to process, If one data has validation error it will process the next data without canceling all the process. Currently i do it like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function updateProductsInventory($data)
{
  $errors = array();
  $success = array();
  $results = array();

  foreach ($data as $productData) {
    $errValdation = $this->validateUpdateInventory($productData);
    if (!empty($errValdation)) {
      $errors['validation'][$productData['sku']] = $errValdation;
      continue;
    }
    try {
      $result = $this->updateInventory($data);
      $success['update'][] = $productData['Item No_'];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      $errors['insert'][$productData['sku']] = __("There's something wrong, please try again!");
    }
  }
  if (!empty($errors)) {
    $results['errors'] = $errors;
    if (empty($success)) {
      throw new \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception($results);
    }
  }
  if (!empty($success)) $results['success'] = $errors;
  return $results;
}

public function validateProductInventory($data){
    $errors = array();
    $mandatories = array('sku','qty','warehouse');
    foreach ($mandatories as $mandatory) {
      if (!array_key_exists($mandatory,$data)) {
        $errors[] =   $mandatory . ' ' . __("is Empty");
        continue;
      }elseif(empty($data[$mandatory])) {
        $errors[] =   $mandatory . ' ' . __("is Empty");
        continue;
      }
      if ($mandatory == 'qty') {
        if ($data[$mandatory] < 0) {
          $errors[] = __("Inventory must be Greater or equal to 0");
        }
      }elseif($mandatory == 'sku'){
        $productId = $this->productFactory->create()->getIdBySku($data[$mandatory]);
        if (empty($productId)) {
          $errors[] = __("The Product with the %1 SKU doesn't exist.",$data[$mandatory]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

error results:

```
[
    {
        "validation": {
            "BM0011": [
                "The Product with the AKWLHK0001 SKU doesn't exist."
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

success results:

```
[
    {
        "update": [
            "W1K147353BA5XX"
        ]
    }
]
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to return an API result, and I don't think this is very neat, is there a recommendation to improve the result of my web API?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function updateProductsInventory($data)
{
  $errors = array();
  $success = array();
  $results = array();

  foreach ($data as $productData) {
    $errValdation = $this->validateUpdateInventory($productData);
    if (!empty($errValdation)) {
      $errors[$productData['sku']] = $errValdation;
      continue;
    }
    try {
      $result = $this->updateInventory($data);
      if ($result) {
        $success[] = $productData['Item No_'];
      }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      $errors['insert'][$productData['sku']] = __("There's something wrong, please try again!");
    }
  }
  if (!empty($errors) && empty($success)) {
    $results['errors'] = $errors;
      throw new \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception($results);
  }
  $results['success'] = $success ?? "";
  $results['errors']  = $errors ?? "";

  return $results;
}

public function validateProductInventory($data){
    $errors = array();
    $mandatories = array('sku','qty','warehouse');
    foreach ($mandatories as $mandatory) {
      if (!array_key_exists($mandatory,$data)) {
        $errors[] =   $mandatory . ' ' . __("is Empty");
        continue;
      }elseif(empty($data[$mandatory])) {
        $errors[] =   $mandatory . ' ' . __("is Empty");
        continue;
      }
      if ($mandatory == 'qty') {
        if ($data[$mandatory] < 0) {
          $errors[] = __("Inventory must be Greater or equal to 0");
        }
      }elseif($mandatory == 'sku'){
        $productId = $this->productFactory->create()->getIdBySku($data[$mandatory]);
        if (empty($productId)) {
          $errors[] = __("The Product with the %1 SKU doesn't exist.",$data[$mandatory]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Thank you